# Setting element value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have the below element:

```
<input type="text" value="" tabindex="1" size="15" onblur="UpCaseSearch(this)" name="name">
```

which is an **empty** text field.

I want to set text into that field and I can successfully do that using a command like that (when I say successfully I mean that I can see that field populated with text `test`:

```
window.frames[1].document.getElementsByName('name')[2].value = "test"
```

I have 2 questions however:

1. When I look at that element on the page I see that the `value` attribute is still empty `""`. Why is that? Where is the actual text that I can see in that field is coming from?
2. If I try the below command, it will actually set the `value` but then the field remains empty:

   window.frames[1].document.getElementsByName('name')[2].setAttribute('value', 'test')

So it looks like that's not the same value in both cases. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

In short, the `value` attribute in source-code (and dom) serves as 'defaultValue'.

For *example*, imagine this input-field (which is a common way to use this functionality):

```
<input type="text" 
      value="your name here" 
    onfocus="if (this.value===this.defaultValue) this.value='';" 
     onblur="if (this.value==='') this.value=this.defaultValue;" >
```

In other words, to set the default value in html-markup (`<input value="your_value" type="text">`) and from javascript you set the value-*attribute* (using the *methods*: `var val=elm.getAttribute('value')` and `elm.setAttribute('value', val)`.
<sub>This is also why (as you have seen) these attributes propagate to the element's `outerHTML` (and thus the element's parent `innerHTML`).</sub>

However to get/set the element's *current* value *property* you use: `var val=elm.value` and `elm.value=val`.

Sidenote: Almost the same goes for a `textarea`: you can use `.defaultValue` on a `textarea` to retrieve it's `textContent` (but you'd override/change that by setting it's `innerHTML`) while you get/set the current value using `elm.value`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
window.frames[1].document.getElementsByName('srchsnam')[2].value = "Test"
```

Let me know if it worked!

Comment: Have you even read the question?

Comment: It reads that he is success in setting the value attribute but the values is not seen in the textfield. isn't that his problem?

Comment: @Vohuman This is probably my fault as I accidentally posted the same line with different values for class name. I fixed it later but this answer was given prior to that.